# Which to use React hooks or Redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, redux

I need to create authentication with reactjs and node/express. Previously I did that with redux and right now I am not up-to-date with react-hooks.I saw somewhere in article that this  can replace redux.This is little confusing for me, so I need good suggestion about this, and if you can share some article or example of react(updated) node/express authentication,then please share.
Thanks for attention to my wired question))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with your app. When you deal with more complex logic or flows in your application, I personally prefer Redux for making the code cleaner and easier to manage. If it's a simpler flow application, you can definitely leverage on hooks and context to create your own state management as good as Redux.

However, if the application ever has the potential to grow into a complex app (like requires middleware, debugging tools, etc.) I'd recommend starting with Redux so you don't have to switch from hooks into Redux later.

First, understand what Redux offers (and how it helps in a complex app):

- https://redux.js.org/

Some related good articles as requested, if you want to build your own redux-hooks:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/use-hooks-and-context-not-react-and-redux/
- https://gorillalogic.com/blog/how-to-build-your-own-redux-state-management-implementation-based-on-hooks/